# Partition an iterator with side effects

Tags: rust

I want to partition an iterator with some side effects. A simple example to explain what I want is like this:

```rust
let arr = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let (even, odd) = arr.iter_mut().partition(
  |num: &&mut usize| if num % 2 == 0 { num *= 2; true } else { false }
);
// Expect even = [ 4, 8, 12 ]
// Expect odd = [ 1, 3, 5 ]
```

Well, this indeed is not working since the num is `&&mut usize` in `partition`. I wonder if there is a way to achieve this in Rust without doing it separately. (i.g. remove `num *= 2` and use a `map` after partition)

The reason I don't want to do this in separate steps is that the side effect might be costly. Though my current situation is trying to implement my own `#[derive(Builder)]` with codes as follows (using separate steps):

```rust
let (required_fields, optional_fields): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) =
    fields.partition(|f| extract_type_from_option(&f.ty).is_none());
let (required_fields_ident, required_fields_ty): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = 
required_fields
    .iter()
    .map(|f| (f.ident.clone().unwrap(), f.ty.clone()))
    .unzip();
let (optional_fields_ident, optional_fields_ty): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = 
optional_fields
    .iter()
    .map(|f| {
        (
            f.ident.clone().unwrap(),
            extract_type_from_option(&f.ty).unwrap(),
        )
    })
    .unzip();
```

Comment: Why don't you want to do it in separate steps? Why is `partition` followed by `map` no good? It might help if you can show us a more realistic example. This one is better solved without side effects.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I have updated the question. The main reason is that I think side effects might be costly and want to do it fewer times.

Comment: If there are costly side effects happening, then you shouldn't be using `partition` *or* `map` but a good old-fashioned `for` loop. It can do everything, and people expect it to have side effects, whereas most of the Rust iterator operations are generally expected to be pure functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can take ownership and partition at the same time with [`.partition_map()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_map) from the [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate. The feature advertised is the ability to partition to different types, but as part of that it passes the item and not just a reference to it:

```
use itertools::{Either, Itertools}; // 0.10.5

let (even, odd): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = arr.iter_mut().partition_map(|num: &mut usize| {
    if *num % 2 == 0 {
        *num *= 2;
        Either::Left(num)
    } else {
        Either::Right(num)
    }
});
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c11ee54703b8884eebf072034075684a).